# dropdownlist remain selected value unchanged when refresh the page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a dropdown list like below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" cssclass="ddStyle" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="company" DataValueField="SECid" Width="100%" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select distinct secid, company from .... order by company"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The VB behind is

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Selection As String = Nothing


    If Not DropDownList.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then Selection = DropDownList.SelectedValue
    Session("Selected") = Selection



End Sub
```

I want to achieve that when I refresh the page after I made selection to the dropdwonlist, the dropdownlist won't return to "--select one--", rather, keep its last selected item. I wonder what's the solution for it?

Thanks for advice!

Comment: can you show me your code-behind? What do you have in your Page_Load?

Comment: Hi, the VB code behind is for a button click (as posted above). I currently don't have any page_load sub.

Comment: Wait, maybe I miss understood: You DONT want the DropDownList to change the selected item after any refreash? So when the page refreshes you want the DropDownList to keep its last selected item?

Comment: Hi, it seems doesn't work. I don't want "--Select One--" to be selected after refresh. If I had selected ABC in dropdownlist, I want to keep ABC selected even after refresh the page.

Comment: I understand now. I edited your question and made it a bit clearer. You should follow LakshmilNarayana approach, if you dont understand it, I can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of what *LakshmiNarayana* ment:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select One --"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Apple"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Orange"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

**VB Code-Behind:**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Not Session("Selected") Is Nothing Then
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session("Selected").ToString
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Selection As String = Nothing

    If Not DropDownList1.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
        Selection = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
        Session("Selected") = Selection
    End If       
End Sub
```

Comment: I recently realized that when I do cascading dropdownlist (not using AJAX), the VB code would return error when I refresh the page (as the dropdownlist always return to the first item). I wonder if there is a way to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to check if `Session("Selected")`  value contains a value, and bind it to the list box in page_load, in a `!isPostback` block.

Checkout this [forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1693223.aspx) for other approaches of achieving this.

Comment: Hi, is it something like  Protected Sub Page_reload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If DropDownList.SelectedValue = "" Then
            DropDownList.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub I tried but still doesn't work?